# NSUnknownKeyException error handling

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

What do you do when you're getting the unknown key error but you're keys are key compliant and there aren't issues with your IBOutlet properties? Everything is correctly connected (all storyboards), I've restarted Xcode several times, I've searched similar questions on here and I still can't find the correct answer for my situation. It's been 5 hours.

[image]

If you don't mind looking at it, here's a link to the download [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o72uy67i9wtvd7g/POP.zip?dl=0)

[image]

[image]

Comment: It appears you are trying to set the `email` property of a `User` object.

Comment: @Paulw11 Yeah I am. Its a field in the database structure

Comment: Well your `User` object doesn't have an `email` property

Comment: @Paulw11 yeah it does. Its saved as a String

Comment: No, it doesn’t, since an exception was thrown stating that `User` isn’t key-value compliant for `email`. You should add relevant code to your question.

Comment: @Paulw11 just did

Comment: Please add code, not screenshots

Comment: You may need to tag your vars explicitly as `@objc`

Comment: @Paulw11 so like "@objc var email: String?"

Answer (score 0):

As recommended by Paulw11, I just had to add the "@objc" tag for the variables and now its working smoothly